# git log shows skipped lines on my bash

Tags: git, bash

I ran into this strange "git log" output on my bash on RHEL.  See below:

```
commit 9632da8405cb50ef4d4897254869523ee7a8dbb8
Author: AAA BBB <aaa@bbb.com>
Date:   Tue Aug 23 19:47:43 2016 -0700

   Some messages ....

...skipping...
Author: XXXX YYYY <xxx@yyy.com>
Date:   Sun Aug 21 11:18:48 2016 -0700

   Some messages for this hash ...
```

See "...skipping...".  I don't know where this line is added and how a few commits are skipped and replaced by this line.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please, post the bash code which executes the "git log" command.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Skipping is showing because `git` is using `less` as a pager by default.

`less` "skips" line when you scroll up or down manually. Instead use up and down arrow keys from keyboard.

Comment: @Change-the-world Yes, that's what it means. Or using Ctrl + PageUp, or anything in theses lines.